# Excel VBA - Extra Sheets cause my VBA to run slower

Tags: vba, performance, excel

I have a macro that runs really fast when I run a VBA sub/function that interacts with 2 sheets, but when I add others sheets that have nothing to do with the sub calculation, the sub takes 10x longer to get executed. I've trying to disable the others sheets to get my sub/function faster again, but I couldn't find a solution. Anyone could help me ?? Thanks in advance.

That's the part of my code that gets slower with the other sheets added :

```
Dim i, j, k As Integer
'Fluxo de Caixa iterators
i = 11
j = 10
'DB interators
k = 2
'cachFlowRef row
rowReference = Range("cashFlowRef").Row

Debug.Print timer.TimeElapsed

Do Until Cells(i, 2) = "T"
    If Cells(i, 2) <> "" Then
        Do Until Cells(rowReference, j).Value = ""
            If Cells(i, j).Value <> 0 Then

              With Sheets("FLUXO_DB")
                .Cells(k, 1).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value 'tipo
                .Cells(k, 2).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value 'plano de contas
                .Cells(k, 3).Value = Cells(i, j).Value 'valor
                .Cells(k, 4).Value = Cells(3, j).Value 'data
                .Cells(k, 5).Value = getTrimestre(Cells(10, j).Value) 'trimestre
                .Cells(k, 6).Value = Year(Cells(10, j).Value) 'ano
              End With

              k = k + 1
            End If
            j = j + 1
        Loop

    End If
    j = 10
    i = i + 1
Loop

Debug.Print timer.TimeElapsed
```

Comment: Is the workbook with the extra sheets now very large? You may be running into memory issues which would cause the slowdown.

Comment: A hunch is that you are iterating over a huge collection of cells just to change a few.

Comment: I know, but It still work fast with just 2 sheets that the sub makes reference, the problem is when I have others sheets added ( this other sheets have nothing to do with the sheets I'm working with the sub but still makes my code get slower)

Answer (score 0):

Add **Application.Calculation = xlManual** to the start of your code

and add **Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic** to the end.

Comment: I've alredy added ! Sorry , I forgot this part in my code